# How can i define a variable in Json?

Tags: ajax, json, variables

i want define a variable in Json callback.

Code;

```
$("select").change(function () {
          var $variable = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                $variable += $(this).text() + " ";
              });
          $("div.yaz").text($variable);

      $('#result').html('loading...');

    $.getJSON('program-bilgileri.php', function(JSON){
        $('#result').empty();

        $.each(JSON.$variable, function(i, program){
            $('#result')
            .append(program.isim +'<br />')
            .append(program.bilgi+'<br />')
            .append(program.adres+'<hr />');
      });
    });
    })
    .trigger('change');
```

program-bilgileri.php returns;

```
{
   "programlar":[
      {
         "isim":"Zone Alarm",
         "bilgi":"bilgisayarın güvenliğini sağlar",
         "adres":"www.zonealarm.com"
      },
      {
         "isim":"Opera",
         "bilgi":"güvenli ve hızlı bir web tarayıcısıdır",
         "adres":"www.opera.com"
      },
      {
         "isim":"Photoshop",
         "bilgi":"güçlü bir imaj işleme yazılımıdır",
         "adres":"www.adobe.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

The problem is here "$.each(JSON.$variable, function(i, program)" if I define $variable in JSON it isn't working.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think that code does what you think it does.  What do expect `JSON.$variable` to do?  if you expect it to access the key of the object that has that is equal to the value of $variable, then are assuming the wrong thing.  That would be JSON[$variable].

Comment: Post the returned JSON from the `getJSON` request.

Comment: @Corbin i try JSON[$variable], but it doesn't work.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli i don't understand. can you explain with a sample code?

Comment: @mrchad, i am not suggesting something.. i am asking you to edit your question and add what `program-bilgileri.php` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems i see are

- Inside the `change` event you are using `$("select option:selected")` which finds all `select` elements in the page, and not the changed one only.
  use `$(this).children('option:selected')` instead.
- I am assuming that you are allowing multiple selection on the `select` element and that is why you are doing `+=` with the `$variable`.. (*you are also adding a space at the end*). That means, though, that the variable will be something like `"programlar "` or `"programlar somethingelse"`.
  Your returned JSON though has a key of `programlar`. A single word, no spaces.. so when you do `JSON[$variable]` which is the correct way to access an element based on the name in a variable, it does not match.

If the `<select>` element does not allow multiple selection then the solution is

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var $variable = $(this).children("option:selected").text();

    $("div.yaz").text( $variable );

    $('#result').html('loading...');

    $.getJSON('program-bilgileri.php', function(JSON) {
        $('#result').empty();
        $.each(JSON[$variable], function(i, program) {
            $('#result')
                .append(program.isim + '<br />')
                .append(program.bilgi + '<br />')
                .append(program.adres + '<hr />');
        });
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

---

If indeed it is a multiselect and each option can appear in the JSON then you must check for each option found in the variable.

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var $variable = $(this).children("option:selected").map(function(){
                           return $(this).text();
                    }).get();

    $("div.yaz").text( $variable.join(' ') );

    $('#result').html('loading...');

    $.getJSON('program-bilgileri.php', function(JSON) {
        $('#result').empty();

        for (index=0, length = $variable.length; index < length; index ++) {
            $.each(JSON[$variable[index]], function(i, program) {
                $('#result')
                    .append(program.isim + '<br />')
                    .append(program.bilgi + '<br />')
                    .append(program.adres + '<hr />');
            });
        }
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.each(JSON['programlar'], function(i, program) ... );
```

This will iterate over this part of your returned JSON object from PHP:

```
  {
     "isim":"Zone Alarm",
     "bilgi":"bilgisayarın güvenliğini sağlar",
     "adres":"www.zonealarm.com"
  },
  {
     "isim":"Opera",
     "bilgi":"güvenli ve hızlı bir web tarayıcısıdır",
     "adres":"www.opera.com"
  },
  {
     "isim":"Photoshop",
     "bilgi":"güçlü bir imaj işleme yazılımıdır",
     "adres":"www.adobe.com"
  }
```